# How to fix mysql issue with this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> Error Number: 1055
>
> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_name.tbl_gigs.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    tbl_gigs.*, 
    tbl_users.first_name, tbl_users.service_name, tbl_users.last_name, tbl_users.image, 
    tbl_event_type.name_french as name, tbl_event_type.name_french, tbl_event.approval_status as event_appstatus, tbl_event.event_no 
FROM (`tbl_gigs`) 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_event_type` ON `tbl_event_type`.`id` = `tbl_gigs`.`event_type` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_users` ON `tbl_users`.`id` = `tbl_gigs`.`invites` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_event` ON `tbl_event`.`id` = `tbl_gigs`.`event_id` 
WHERE `tbl_gigs`.`status` = '1' AND tbl_gigs.user_id = '261' AND tbl_gigs.event_id != '0' 
GROUP BY `tbl_gigs`.`event_id` 
ORDER BY `tbl_gigs`.`id` desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You are misusing group by which is designed to work with aggregate functions (of which you have none) - You would be better explaining what you are trying to do providing sample data and expected output as text.

Answer (score 2):

I have already user below query

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))
```